# Angular - Form with special features and Geolocation

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am creating a user registration form using Angular 7 and AdminLTE Theme.
I have earlier read Google documentation on Geolocation, but don't know how to apply it to my Angular Project.

1. When a user clicks the address textbox, I want the application to automatically display city, state and country using Google Geolocation or any other means. Then the user selects.

```html
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Google maps api, An Easy package integrated with googlemaps [AGM](https://angular-maps.com/)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are talking about google places auto complete (from what I have understood). I am sharing the link use this. You get the places detail from input text and then bind the relevant values (city, state and country) accordingly.

Here is the link

Link: https://brianflove.com/2016/10/18/angular-2-google-maps-places-autocomplete/

Once you get the data from google places api you can use code similar to following code snippet. Hope it helps.

```
this.address.address_components.forEach(item => {
                    if (item.types.indexOf('locality') !== -1) {
                        this.city = item['long_name'];
                        // Country of the selected address
                    } else if (
                        item.types.indexOf(
                            'administrative_area_level_1'
                        ) !== -1
                    ) {
                        this.state = item['short_name'];
                        // Country of the selected address
                    } else if (item.types.indexOf('country') !== -1) {
                        this.country = item['long_name'];
                    }
                });
```